# How to show image on JSP using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
    //My Controller which handles image and Data
     @RequestMapping(value = "/student/edit/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView editStudent( @PathVariable Integer id,
                                        ModelMap model,
                                        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

      Student student=studentservice.retieveStudent(id); 
                byte[] studentImage = student.getUserImage();
                response.setContentType("image/png");
                response.getOutputStream().write(studentImage);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                model.addAttribute("studentImage","studentImage")
                model.addAttribute("studentName",student.getStudentName);
                model.addAttribute("studentDetails",student.getStudentDetails);
            return new ModelAndView("viewstudent");
        }

student.jsp
<a href=student/edit/12><h1>Edit<h1></a>


 viewstudent.jsp   
<div>
 <table> <tr><td>Student Name=${studentName}</td></tr>
          <tr><td>StudentDetails=${studentDetails}</td></tr>
     <img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,"<c:out value='${studentImage}'/>" alt="my image" />
</table>
```

when i click on the link Edit  only the image is getting shown on browser and viewstudent.jsp page is not getting displayd,How do I show image  in viewstudent.jsp along with data After fetching from DB

Comment: What you are attaching to "studentImage" is a string. model.addAttribute("studentImage","studentImage").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don' seem to understand how HTTP and HTML works.

To display an HTML page containing an image, you need two HTTP requests. The first one gets the HTML page. The HTML page contains a tag like

```
<img src="location_of_the_image" />
```

Then the browser parses the HTML, sees that it contains an `img` tag, and sendsa second HTTP request to the location of the image. The response to this second HTTP request contains the bytes of the image.

So you should have two methods in your controller: one which returns a ModelAndView used to render the HTML page, and a second one which loads the bytes of the image, sets the content type, and sends the bytes to the response OutputStream.